# import file path autocomplete in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've just switched to vscode from atom. I miss the path autocomplete when you import a file. In atom, all the files that are in my workspace are automatically searched for the matching keyword. However, in vscode, only the node modules and the relative directories are searched. This forces me to guess the directory structure to get to the file I want to import. Is there a way to make vscode search for all the files in the workspace directory (excluding external modules)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) for vs code...I use it all the time and it is great.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. it still requires you to specify the directory structure to recursively search the file.

Comment: Have you tried [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that...without more info on what is going on I can't really offer any help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `jsconfig.json` file in your project root, with `target` and `module` `complierOptions`, than VSCode will autocomplete your imports.
Official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig
An example of `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    ".cache",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/.cache/*",
    "**/build/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for autocompletion for importing css, images, or anything other than js/jsx/ts/tsx/json.